# I want to find the date in the description of AMI image

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to find date string in the description of the image.I have done this:

[image]

I am getting this output.
[image]

and when I am trying to uncomment the line it shows this.
[image]

I want to find the date in the description of AMI image, so that I can find the images registered on that date.

Comment: Now you can also get the creation date from a dedicated field _CreationDate_. For example, from the CLI: aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-1a2b3c4d --query 'Images[0].CreationDate'

Comment: thanks Guy, appreciate your help, but if you can tell a way to find the creation date of ami in python.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use the Python SDK often, but I wanted to point out that the information is now available as a field in the output to the call to describe-images, and you will have the same output field in your python call.

Comment: its ok Guy. No issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code:-

```
curdate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")    #returns 17/04/2015.
```

Your present curdate is returning "04/17/15". But this is not what you are trying to find in the given string.

Also `ami_image.description.find([curdate])` would not work. `find` method of a string needs str value.

But for your requirements the above solution may not be sufficient because you may not always know what is to be compared. So you can use `re` to get the date from description.

```
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile("([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})")
>>> m = patt.search(ami_image.description)
>>> m.groups(0)
('17/04/2015',)
```

Comment: great to know that its working. Can you please upvote and accept the answer in that case :), this would help us both gain some reputation.

Comment: Barun I would have done that since to rate 15 reputation points are needed, I dont have 15 reputation points.

Comment: But you can accept this answer by clicking the tick sign on left of the answer ;)

Comment: Barun is there any way in boto where i can find the creation date of ami image.